# Translating MS Access SQL select query to VBA. Breaks when select with aggregation sum function

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

**Background**

I'm trying to use Excel VBA to load data from Microsoft Office Access database. 
The code was worked  fine and I am now trying to add an extra column `Position` drawn from the datebasetable named `EqBucket` into the final result table

The SQL works find in Access but it doesn't parse through to VBA. 
The code break when I add in

```
SUM(Eq_Buckets.Position) AS PositionOfSum
```

I'm guess it has to do with the aggregation sum wrapped around the column because this issue has never come up with other direct referenced columns.

Appreciate for any pointers. Thanks

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

**Info:**
1. SQL string is stored in Sheets("SQL").Range("A1").value
2. Database tables `Eq_SingleName_LBU`, `Eq_Buckets` << this is where the position data are stored 
3. `Eq_Portfolio_Ref` is just a reference table which could be ignored

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
**IF I remove "Sum(Eq_Buckets.Position) AS PositionOfSum" the code works in VBA

**Here is the FULLY working SQL code in MS Access:**

```
SELECT Eq_SingleName_LBU.Identifier AS Identifier, Eq_SingleName_LBU.Issuer AS Issuer, Eq_SingleName_LBU.MV_USD AS MV, Sum(Eq_Buckets.Position) AS PositionOfSum, Eq_SingleName_LBU.Issuer_Weight AS [Issuer Weight], Eq_SingleName_LBU.Test_Limit AS Limit, Eq_SingleName_LBU.Room_Limit AS [Remaining Limit], Eq_SingleName_LBU.Data_Date
FROM Eq_SingleName_LBU INNER JOIN (Eq_Buckets INNER JOIN Eq_Portfolio_Ref ON Eq_Buckets.Composite_Portfolio = Eq_Portfolio_Ref.BBG_Account_Codes) ON Eq_SingleName_LBU.Identifier = Eq_Buckets.BB_UniqueID
Where Eq_Buckets.Data_Date = (#03/12/2020#) and Eq_SingleName_LBU.UnderTest="Y"
GROUP BY Eq_SingleName_LBU.Identifier, Eq_SingleName_LBU.Issuer, Eq_SingleName_LBU.MV_USD, Eq_SingleName_LBU.Issuer_Weight, Eq_SingleName_LBU.Test_Limit, Eq_SingleName_LBU.Room_Limit, Eq_SingleName_LBU.Data_Date
HAVING (((Eq_SingleName_LBU.Data_Date) In (#03/12/2020#)))
ORDER BY Eq_SingleName_LBU.Data_Date;
```

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

**Here is the VBA code that the SQL string needs to fit through**

```
Sub ADOImportFromAccessTable()

'On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual
Sheets("EQ1_SQL").Visible = True

    Dim con As Object
    Dim rst As Object
    Dim dbPath As String

    dbPath = "\\Db\Asset_db.accdb"
    Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbPath
    con.Open

    Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

'This is where the SQL code will be referenced.
strSql = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SQL").Range("A1").Value
Debug.Print strSql
strSql = Replace(strSql, "{date1}", Date_1)
Debug.Print strSql
strSql = Replace(strSql, "{date2}", Date_2)

rst.Open strSql, con, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    con.Close
    Set con = Nothing

End sub
```

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

**Here is the error message I get from Excel VB editor**

```
Here is the error I get from VB editor.
Run-tme error '-2147467259 (80004005);: 
Method 'Open' of object' _ Recordset' failed
```

Comment: If you're calling this from Excel why not store your SQL in a worksheet cell?  Much easier than all that concatenation.

Comment: I need the sql to be a string to make feed it dynamic variables (different dates), but how exactly can I call the SQL stored in my worksheet?

Comment: `sql = Thisworkbook.sheets("SQL").Range("A1").Value`  If you need to vary certain parts then use tokens and replace them after fetching the text from the cell.  `sql = Replace(sql, "{date1}", Date_1)` for example

Comment: I've tried pasting in the working SQL code in to a cell and make VBA call that cell.value, but I don't think it works. 

By pasting in the SQL code directly in a cell, the string itself is still in SQL format and VBA wont understand it. The string itself needs to be in the right format and parse through the VBA code that calls the access.db records. I have added the VBA calling access code in the original question to clarify. Any other ideas?

Comment: It's no different getting the string from a cell than having it hard-coded in your VBA.  What happens when you run that code?  Try using a simple SQL statement first, to make sure you have the basics correct.

Comment: Thanks, referanceing directly to a cell makes the vba code much cleaner. I've tested with a simple sql code and it works. So the issues is with the SQL code? 
I emphasize, the exact same SQL code works in access but it breaks when I run it through VBA.  

Here is the error I get from VB editor.
Run-tme error '-2147467259 (80004005);: 
Method 'Open' of object' _ Recordset' failed

Comment: I've Simplified the questions slightly by removing the alias and joins, the issues is still the same with the select Sum(Positions), any idea? Thanks

Comment: I did a test in Excel VBA to open recordset with a very simple SQL using Sum(). It works. Suggest you do that and when it works, build more complex SQL.

Comment: Position may have another meaning in VBA so try Sum(B.[Position])

Comment: Can you run your query from Excel using a non-VBA method such as https://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/excel/how-to-query-an-access-database-tables-from-excel-2019/   ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding brackets around `Position` ie  `Sum(B.[Position])`,

You can shorten the SQL by using table name aliases, for example

```vb
strSQL = " SELECT A.Identifier AS Identifier, A.Issuer AS Issuer, A.MV_USD AS MV," & _
             "   Sum(B.[Position]) AS PositionOfSum, " & _
             "   A.Issuer_Weight AS [Issuer Weight]," & _
             "   A.Test_Limit AS Limit, " & _
             "   A.Room_Limit AS [Remaining Limit]," & _
             "   A.Data_Date" & _
             " FROM Eq_SingleName_LBU AS A " & _
             " INNER JOIN Eq_Buckets AS B" & _
             " ON A.Identifier = B.BB_UniqueID" & _
             "   WHERE B.Data_Date = #2020/12/03# " & _
             "   AND A.UnderTest = 'Y' " & _
             " GROUP BY A.Identifier, A.Issuer," & _
             "   A.MV_USD, A.Issuer_Weight, A.Test_Limit," & _
             "   A.Room_Limit, A.Data_Date" & _
             " HAVING A.Data_Date IN (#2020/12/03#) " & _
             " ORDER BY A.Data_Date"
```

Comment: Thanks it woks Position ie Sum(B.[Position])